# How to iterate DataFrame of strings and apply if condtion over the result

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement

I am trying to iterate over a dataframe using the if condition to return a value if a string is equal to the string at the ith position in the dataframe.

I get following error by running the example code

> ```
> (`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`):
> ```

```
 df = {'step_ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4], 'step_name':['CC_Dchg', 'CC_Dchg', 'Rest', 'Rest', 'CC_Chg', 
    'CC_Chg', 'Rest', 'Rest']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)

    chg_step = []
    a = []

    for i in df:
        if df['step_name'] == 'CC_Chg':
            a = SiO_1['step_ID']
            chg_step = chg_step + a
        else:
            continue
```

What is the correct syntax to check if `df['step_name'] == 'CC_Chg'` is True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly, you need the `step_ID` of rows where `step_name` is equal to a given value. In pandas, you shouldn't have to write your own loops (or only in extreme situation). Instead, here is an alternative:

```py
# step by step

# do the comparison step_name == X for each row.
# The result is a boolean pandas Series
mask = df['step_name'] == 'CC_Chg' 
# The boolean pandas series can be used to select only some rows.
# Then, we can retrieve the step_ID column for those rows only.
# The result is again a pandas Series
chg_step_series = df[mask].step_ID # this is a series
# A pandas series can be converted to a numpy array using values,
# and then a list by calling tolist()
chg_step_series.values.tolist() # this is a list: [3,3]
```

Or, in one line:

```py
chg_step = df[df.step_name == 'CC_Chg'].step_ID.values.tolist()
```

Comment: This is perfect, Thanks! I knew there had to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: You are welcome. Please, don't forget to mark the question as answered (tickmark on the left of my answer). Happy coding !